# Nginx не верно отрабатывает конфиг

Tags: nginx, debian

У меня в главном файле конфигурации прописан такой инклуд

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

В этой папке есть 3 файла конфигурации: site.com, site.ru и mail.site.com.

Для site.com и site.ru все отрабатывает хорошо, а вот mail.site.com оно как бы не видит. Постоянно дает 404 и в access.log для этого домена нету записей, они попадают в общий.

Почему такое может быть?

Конфиг для mail.site.com

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mail.site.com www.mail.site.com;

  location / {
    root /var/www/mail.site.com;
    index index.html;
  }
```

Файл index.html по указанному пути есть

Добавляю конфиг для site.com

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    set $base_root        /var/www/site.com;
    root        $base_root;
    index       index.html;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/site.com.log combined;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/site.com.error.log error;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen      148.251.77.9:80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

P.S.

Прошу прощения, забыл указать, что домен работает через cloudflare. Может это имеет значение.

Добавлю еще содержимое /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: `sudo nginx -T` не ругается ни на что?

Comment: нет, говорит, что все ок

Comment: Ну показывайте что он вывел

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Это -t, а не -T

Comment: вывел много разной информации, в том числе конфиги для всех 3х сайтов.

Comment: Ну ищите тогда опечатки. И вообще, в error.log заглядывали?

Comment: Скорее всего в site.com стоит *.site.com у директивы server_name

Comment: да, там нет ошибок

Comment: После добавления нового конфига `nginx` то перезапускался? хотя бы эта команда  `nginx -s reload` выполнялась?

Answer (score 0):

Выполните

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mail.site.com /etc/sites-enabled/mail.site.com
```

И перезапустите NGINX

Добавлю:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mail.site.com www.mail.site.com;

  location / {
    root /var/www/mail.site.com;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri / = 404;
  }
```

Comment: я так делал, симлинк создан

Comment: А можете дополнить вопрос полным листингом конфига site.com и mail.site.com?

Comment: добавил для site.com, для mail.site.com был изначально

Comment: А может быть такое, что сервер Вас автоматически переадресует с http на https, а 443 порт для субдомена не прописан и он перекидывает на основной домен?

Comment: переадресации нет, он открывается по http

Comment: Вообще странно. Попробуйте конфиг поддомена перенести в основной конфиг.

Comment: уже делал, все так же не работает

Comment: Пробовали заставить его искать файлы через try_files?

Comment: нет, как это сделать?

Comment: Добавил в свой ответ

Comment: добавил, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Значит будем дальше угадывать, надо же добить эту проблему.
Попробуйте добавить default_server в mail.site.com:

listen       80 default_server;

Comment: все так же, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Исходя из всех попыток, я думаю, что дело не в конфигах. Надо копать глубже.